# How to get Instance name in CommandBox CF 2018?

Tags: coldfusion, components, commandbox

I recently started using commandBox to run ColdFusion in my local environment. After I played around for a while one issue I run into was related to adminapi. Here is the code that I use in one of my projects:

```
adminObj = createObject("component","cfide.adminapi.runtime");
instance = adminObj.getInstanceName();
```

This code is pretty straight forward and work just fine if I install traditional ColdFusion Developer version on my machine. I tried running this on commandBox: `"app":{ "cfengine":"adobe@2018.0.7" }`

After I run the code above this is the error message I got:

```
Object Instantiation Exception.
Class not found: com.adobe.coldfusion.entman.ProcessServer
```

The first debugging step was to check if component exists. I simply checked that like this:

```
adminObj = createObject("component","cfide.adminapi.runtime");
writeDump(adminObj);
```

The result I got on the screen was this:

```
component CFIDE.adminapi.runtime
        extends CFIDE.adminapi.base
METHODS
```

Then I tried this to make sure method exists in the scope:

```
adminObj = createObject("component","cfide.adminapi.runtime");
writeDump(adminObj.getInstanceName);
```

The output looks like this, and that confirmed that method `getInstanceName` exists.

```
function getInstanceName
Arguments:  none
ReturnType: any
Roles:   
Access: public
Output: false
DisplayName:     
Hint:   returns the current instance name
Description:
```

The error is occurring only if I call the function `getInstanceName()`. Does anyone know what could be the reason of this error? Is there any solution for this particular problem? Like I already mentioned this method works in traditional ColdFusion 2018 developer environment. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in Adobe ColdFusion.  The CFC you're creating is trying to create an instance of a specific Java class.  I recognize the class name `com.adobe.coldfusion.entman.ProcessServer` as being related to their enterprise manager which controls features only available in certain versions of CF as well as features only available on their "standard" Tomcat installation (as opposed to a J2E deployment like CommandBox).

Please report this to Adobe in the [Adobe bug tracker](https://tracker.adobe.com/#/home) as they appear to be incorrectly detecting the servlet installation.  I worked with them a couple years ago to improve their servlet detection on CommandBox, but I guess they still have some issues.

As a workaround, you could try and find out what jar that class is from on a non-CommandBox installation of Adobe ColdFusion and add it to the path, but I can't promise that it will work and that it won't have negative consequences.

Comment: Brad, thanks for the response. I spent a lot of time trying to fix this issue. I will reach out to Adobe and report the bug. Also, I will try the solution that you proposed.